# Blackboard or another architecture - thoughts please

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design, blackboard

I have to choose a suitable architecture to develop a system that models an emergency call/dispatch service..

- Calls come in from a person in need.
- Telephone operator records details (Name, location etc).
- System dispatches ambulance from nearest hospital.
- System checks medical database
- System passes medical history and patient info onto a PDA/Smartphone within the dispatched Ambulance.
- Paramedics send update with location and actions taken.

I was thinking that a Blackboard architecture would suit this - but the dispatching of data / client request made, when sending info to the ambulance, would contradict the BB architecture.

I can use both classic, hybrid, emerging or experimental architecture patterns - so long as they work and fit the problem..

Can anyone give me some advice, please?

Comment: Don't succumb to "small boy with a pattern" syndrome.  Let me guess: you were just presented with Blackboard pattern.  I'd say that an event based architecture using publish/subscribe would be better.  Think Netty and protobuf.

Comment: The module the coursework relates to is entitled, "Software Architecture".. So it's less about getting a prototype working and more how the prototype is designed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observer, possibly chain-of-responsibility as well.

All entities observe the call. If there's any element of a chain of responders who have to decide on wheter to handle or forward a request, you need chain-of-respontibility.